# Relação das cidades dos Estados via GET do código dos estados

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando criar um modo de que o próprio usuário possa cadastrar a sua Cidade e seu Bairro.

Porém eu não estou sabendo como fazer com que quando o usuário seleciona o estado desejado, seja relacionado somente as cidades referente ao estado que ele selecionou.

Por exemplo, eu cadastrei no estado do Rio de Janeiro a cidade de Armações dos Búzios, e no estado de São Paulo cadastrei a cidade de Araraquara.

Mas quando seleciono o estado de São Paulo para cadastrar o Bairro na cidade de Araraquara, na relação de cidades aparece a cidade que foi cadastrada no Rio de Janeiro, ou seja a cidade de Armações dos Búzios também.

Se os amigos puderem dar uma analisada nos códigos que estou usando, e me dizer como solucionar este problema, ficarei muito agradecido.

Abaixo relaciono os Código.

Seleção de estados: estado.php

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
$dp =  $_POST['cod_estado'];
echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='cad_cidades.php?cod_estado=$dp'</script>";
}
?>
<form name="enter" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Selecione o estado em que será Cadastra a Cidade</label><br /><br />
<select name="cod_estado">
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estados ORDER BY nome ASC");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $estados =  $res['cod_estado'];?>"><?php echo $estados =  $res['nome'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select><br /><br />
<input class="input" type="submit" name="enter" value="Avançar"/>
</form>
```

Cadastramento de Cidades: cad_cidades.php

```
<?php
        $dp =  $_POST['cod_estado'];
        include "conexao.php";
        $cod_estado = $_GET['cod_estado'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estados WHERE cod_estado = '$cod_estado'");
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        if(isset($_POST['cad_cid'])){
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $uf = $_POST['uf']; 
            $cod_estado = $_GET['cod_estado'];  
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE cod_estado = '".$_POST['cod_estado']."' AND nome = '".$_POST['nome']."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1){
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= cidade.php?cod_estado=".$cod_estado."'>
                  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                  window.alert(\"Esta Cidade já esta Cadastrada! Por favor, tente outra Cidade! Obrigado!!!\");</script>";
        }else{
            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cidades VALUES ('$cod_estado', '$uf', 'NULL', '$nome')")or die(mysql_error());
        if($insert == ''){
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
            window.alert('Erro ao cadastrar Cidade!!!');
            </script>";
        }else{
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= cidade.php?cod_cidade=".$cod_cidade."'>
            <script language='javascript'>
            window.alert('Cidade cadastrada com sucesso!!!');
            </script>";
        }}}
        ?>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <?php
        include 'conexao.php';
            $uf = $_GET['uf'];
            $nome = $_GET['nome'];
            $cod_estado = $_GET['cod_estado'];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estados WHERE cod_estado = '$cod_estado'");
            $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        ?>  
        <label>Cadastre sua Cidade agora, no Estado - <?php echo $res['nome']; ?>/<?php echo $res['uf']; ?></label><br />
        <form name="cad_cid" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="cod_estado" value="<?php echo $cod_estado ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="uf" value="<?php echo $res['uf']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input type="text" name="nome" value="" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="cad_cid" value="Cadastre a Cidade" />
        </form>
```

Relação de Cidades já Cadastradas: cidade.php

```
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
        $dp =  $_POST['cod_cidade'];
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='cad_bairros.php?cod_cidade=$dp'</script>";
        }
        ?>
        <form name="enter" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Selecione a cidade que será Cadastro o Bairro</label><br /><br />
        <select name="cod_cidade">
        <?php
        include 'conexao.php';
            $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cidades ORDER BY nome ASC");
            while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cidades =  $res['cod_cidade'];?>"><?php echo $cidades =  $res['nome'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select><br /><br />
        <input class="input" type="submit" name="enter" value="Avançar"/>
        </form>
```

Cadastramento dos Bairros: cad_bairros.php

```
            <?php
        $dp =  $_POST['cod_cidade'];
        include "conexao.php";
        $cod_cidade = $_GET['cod_cidade'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE cod_cidade = '$cod_cidade'");
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        if(isset($_POST['cad_bai'])){
            $cod_estado = $_POST['cod_estado'];
            $nome_cidade = $_POST['nome_cidade'];
            $uf = $_POST['uf'];
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $cod_cidade = $_GET['cod_cidade'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bairros WHERE cod_cidade = '".$_POST['cod_cidade']."' AND nome = '".$_POST['nome']."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1){
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= cad_bairros.php?cod_cidade=".$cod_cidade."'>
                  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                  window.alert(\"Este Bairro já esta Cadastrado! Por favor, confira o nome do Bairro! Obrigado!!!\");</script>";
        }else{
            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO bairros VALUES ('$cod_estado', '$nome_cidade', '$uf', '$cod_cidade', 'NULL', '$nome')")or die(mysql_error());
        if($insert == ''){
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
            window.alert('Erro ao cadastrar Bairro!!!');
            </script>";
        }else{
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= bairro.php'>
            <script language='javascript'>
            window.alert('Cidade cadastrada com sucesso!!!');
            </script>";
        }}}
        ?>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <?php
           include 'conexao.php';
           $nome_cidade = $_GET['nome_cidade'];
           $uf = $_GET['uf'];
           $nome = $_GET['nome'];
           $cod_estado = $_GET['cod_estado'];
           $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE cod_cidade = '$cod_cidade'");
           $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        ?>
        <label>Cadastre o Bairro agora, na Cidade - <?php echo $res['nome']; ?>/<?php echo $res['uf']; ?></label><br />
        <form name="cad_bai" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="cod_estado" value="<?php echo $res['cod_estado']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="nome_cidade" value="<?php echo $res['nome']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="uf" value="<?php echo $res['uf']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="cod_cidade" value="<?php echo $cod_cidade ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input type="text" name="nome" value="" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="cad_bai" value="Cadastre o Bairro" />
        </form>
```

Relação de Bairros já cadastrados: bairro.php

```
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <form name="enter" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Selecione a cidade que será Cadastro o Bairro</label><br /><br />
        <select name="cod_bairro">
             <?php
             include 'conexao.php';
             $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bairros ORDER BY nome ASC");
             while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
             ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $bairros =  $res['cod_bairro'];?>"><?php echo $bairros =  $res['nome'];?></option>
             <?php } ?>
        </select><br />
        <input class="input" type="submit" name="enter" value=""/>

        </form>
```

Desde já gostaria de agradecer pela atenção de todos.

Comment: Você vai precisar utilizar ajax quando algum estado for selecionado uma chamada assíncrona ao servidor retorna as cidades

Comment: Olá Marcelo! Ele funciona puxando página a página. Com o ajax ele não ficaria como o combobox? Ai como eu poderei cadastrar as cidades e os bairros? Desculpe, mas sou leigo nesse assunto, ainda estou aprendendo , se puder dar um exemplo ficarei agradecido. E obrigado pela sua atenção Marcelo.

Comment: Seu problema não é esse código todo, revisa seu código foi colocado php fazendo echo de javascript... separa as responsabilidades, você terá uma visão melhor.